# If every proper quotient is finite, then $G\cong\mathbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Here is my problem:

> Let $G$ is an infinite abelian group. Prove that if every proper quotient is finite, then $G\cong\mathbb Z$.

And here is my incompleted approach:

I know that the quotient subgroup $\frac{G}{tG}$ wherein $tG$ is torsion subgroup of $G$ is always torsion-free. So, if $tG\neq\{0\}$ then here we have $\frac{G}{tG}$ torsion-free and finite simultonously which is a contradiction. Then $G$ is itself a torsion-free group.

Moreover, I assume $G$ be a divisible group, so: $$G\cong\sum\mathbb Q\oplus\sum_{p\in P}\mathbb Z(p^{\infty})$$ As any proper quotient of $G$ is infinite, so I concluded it is not divisible. I confess that I am missing the final part. If my way to this problem untill my last conclusion is valid logically, please help me about the last part of the proof. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a_0\in G$ be a nonzero element. 
Then $\langle a\rangle\cong \mathbb Z$ as $G$ is torsion-free (which you have shown).
Now $Q_0=G/\langle a_0\rangle$ is a finite abelian group.
If $Q_0\cong 1$, we are done.
Otherwise, select $a_1\in G\setminus\langle a_0\rangle$. Then let $Q_1=G/\langle a_0, a_1\rangle$, etc.

The orders of the finite groups $Q_0, Q_1, \ldots$ are strictly decreasing as long as they are $>1$, hence we ultimately find an $a_n$ with $G=\langle a_1, \ldots,a_n\rangle$.
Thus $G$ is a finitely generated abelian group. A quick check with the classification theorem shows that $G\cong \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks Hagen!. And this quick check is related to quotient of $G$?